# Where can I find documentation about the "By" keyword in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On the example code in this article

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1108855/ways-to-Bind-Multiple-Models-on-a-View-in-MVC

there is a code phrase:
"@comment.Comments ( By @comment.Commentedby )

What is this "By" word? Where can i  find documentation on it? Is it Linq?

Comment: It’s an English word that will be shown in the web page when run. It’s not code

Comment: For reference about the uses of the `@` in Razor: https://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Comment: It's part of plain text representation on HTML between tags (also unrelated with any code in both server & client-side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"By" is just a word. It's not an ASP.NET keyword or anything - in given example it just points the author.
After the page is rendered it would be displayed like:

> This is a comment (By Example Author)

Comment: Can't believe i missed this. Had seen new things like As recently XD. I thought it was sorting By or something